# У вас отложены (held) битые пакеты

Tags: debian, apt-get

При попытке установить `libreoffice-core` (или другие пакеты), выскакивает ошибка:

```
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 libreoffice-core : Зависит: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.3.3) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: ure (>= 4.2~) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libboost-date-time1.55.0 но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libclucene-contribs1 (>= 2.3.3.4) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libclucene-core1 (>= 2.3.3.4) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libcmis-0.4-4 (>= 0.4.0) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libgltf-0.0-0 (>= 0.0.2) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libglu1-mesa но он не будет установлен или
                                    libglu1
                    Зависит: libharfbuzz-icu0 (>= 0.9.18) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libhunspell-1.3-0 (>= 1.3.3) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libicu52 (>= 52~m1-1~) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libmythes-1.2-0 но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libodfgen-0.1-1 но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: librevenge-0.0-0 но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: uno-libs3 (>= 4.3.0~alpha) но он не будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

Как это можно попытаться вылечить? У меня *Debian 8 Jessie x64*.

**UPD_0:** Удалил все из репозиториев, осталось только:

```
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

`sources.list.d` тоже чист.

Для "лечения" пытался выполнить:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf //Не удалилась какая-то папка
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Вывод `apt-cache policy libreoffice-common libreoffice-core`:

```
libreoffice-common:
  Установлен: (отсутствует)
  Кандидат:   1:4.3.3-2+deb8u2
  Таблица версий:
     1:5.1.3~rc2-3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:4.3.3-2+deb8u2 500
        500 http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian jessie/main i386 Packages
libreoffice-core:
  Установлен: (отсутствует)
  Кандидат:   1:4.3.3-2+deb8u2
  Таблица версий:
     1:4.3.3-2+deb8u3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:4.3.3-2+deb8u2 500
        500 http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: возможно, вам поможет `sudo apt-get install -F`

Comment: @MaxTimakov, не помогло :(.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, и до, и после попытки исправлений. Раз 10 точно. :)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, обновил.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, что за `mephi.ru`?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, на сколько я понял, вместо `ftp.ru.debian.org` нужно написать `mirror.yandex.ru`. Если да - не помогло. `security` тоже добавил.

Comment: Возможно версии каких-то установленных из зависимостей пакетов выше, чем в подключенных репозиториях. Понижение версии возможно явным указанием `=версия` после имени пакета.

Comment: @sercxjo, такое может быть при загрузке из оф. репозитория? Да и `testing` у меня был подключен - результат тот же.

Comment: а кроме `testing` не было других репозиториев?

Comment: @sercxjo, были - удалил.

Comment: ну вот значит оттуда и поставили

Comment: Тут больший набор вариантов исправления: [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/947695)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ apt-cache policy libreoffice-common
libreoffice-common:
  Установлен: (отсутствует)
  Кандидат:   1:4.3.3-2+deb8u2

  Таблица версий:
     1:5.1.3~rc2-3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:4.3.3-2+deb8u2 500
        500 http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian jessie/main i386 Packages
```

вы подключали репозиторий(-ии) с более новыми версиями пакетов. информация об этих версиях хранится в `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

удалите из этого файла информацию про версию `1:5.1.3~rc2-3` пакета `libreoffice-common` (начиная со строки `Package: libreoffice-common` и до следующей строки, начинающейся со слова `Package:`, обязательно сохранив разделяющую описания пакетов пустую строку).

и обновите список пакетов:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

---

но вообще, вероятно, более правильным было бы удаление конфигурации неустанавливающихся пакетов. начать можно с того же `libreoffice-common`:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-common
```

Comment: Только хотел сказать "сейчас придёт Александр Баракин и решит все проблемы" )). Мне бы ваши знания.

Comment: `: | ` это способ получить пустую строку? Зачем при этом tee, а не echo?

Comment: `sudo echo > filename` тоже нет?

Comment: Помогло! Присоединюсь к Нику Волкину: "мне бы Ваши знания" :D. А как Вы поняли, что идет несовпадение версий?

Comment: @bukashka101, `1:5.1.3~rc2-3` явно больше `1:4.3.3-2+deb8u2`. проверка: команда `dpkg --compare-versions 1:4.3.3-2+deb8u2 lt 1:5.1.3~rc2-3` возвращает 0. а вывод `policy` я запросил для того, чтобы узнать, что *apt* думает про указанные пакеты, откуда и какие версии собирается ставить.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, блин, при установке вылезло море новых ошибок :). Пойду гуглить...

Comment: @bukashka101, вероятно, всё-таки уже установили какие-то пакеты не из оф. репозитория от установленной версии дистрибутива. из тестинга, например, или вообще откуда-то «слева».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, возможно..... :(

Comment: @bukashka101, кажется, я дал плохой совет. вы не сохранили резервной копии этого файла?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не сохранил... Ладно, завтра буду над этим думать. Пойду лучше книгу по Java почитаю, а завтра, после школы, буду пытаться разобраться с проблемой. В крайнем случае, если не выйдет - задам новый вопрос.

Comment: @bukashka101, там должна быть сохранённая версия. типа `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old`. сохраните куда-нибудь текущую версию файла `/var/lib/dpkg/status` и добавьте в него содержимое сохранённой версии: `cat /var/lib/dpkg/status-old | sudo tee -a /var/lib/dpkg/status >/dev/null`. иначе *dpkg* будет думать, что у вас почти ничего не установлено. это не смертельно, но плохо. и посмотрите на обновление ответа.

Comment: Вот этим мне нравится debian, что БД пакетов в текстовом виде хранится. Ещё можно было попробовать `apt-get install libreoffice-common=1:4.3.3-2+deb8u2`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не вышло у меня исправить новую проблему... Можете помочь? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528186/debian-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй обнови репы в `Software & Update`, и поставь галочки(включи): Официально поддерживается (main), `DFSG-совместимое` ПО с зависимостями от несвободного ПО (`contrib`), `Не-DFCG-совместимое` ПО (`non-free`), Исходный код. Всё это в первой вкладке `Software & Update`, мне помогло.