# Debian ошибка при загрузке пакета и устранения зависимостей

Tags: debian, apt-get, dpkg

После действий в этом вопросе - [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527475/%D0%A3-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-held-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B/527503?noredirect=1#comment655450_527503), возникла следующая проблема:

При попытке установить пакет, вылазят зависимости:

```
rostislav@Rostislav-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install 0ad
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Возможно, для исправления этих ошибок вы захотите воспользоваться «apt-get -f install»:
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 0ad : ПредЗависит: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~)
       Зависит: 0ad-data (>= 0.0.17) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: 0ad-data (<= 0.0.17-1) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: 0ad-data-common (>= 0.0.17) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: 0ad-data-common (<= 0.0.17-1) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libboost-filesystem1.55.0 но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libenet7 но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libgl1-mesa-glx но он не будет установлен или
                       libgl1
       Зависит: libgloox12 но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libicu52 (>= 52~m1-1~) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1:1.3.1) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libminiupnpc10 (>= 1.9.20140610) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libmozjs-24-0 но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libnvtt2 но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libopenal1 (>= 1.14) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libvorbisfile3 (>= 1.1.2) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libwxbase3.0-0 (>= 3.0.2) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libwxgtk3.0-0 (>= 3.0.2) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libx11-6 но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libxcursor1 (> 1.1.2) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libxml2 (>= 2.9.0) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0) но он не будет установлен
 libc6 : Зависит: libgcc1 но он не будет установлен
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt-get -f install», не указывая имени пакета, (или найдите другое решение).
```

А при попытке устранить зависимости, вылазит это:

```
rostislav@Rostislav-PC:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Исправление зависимостей… Готово
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgcc1
НОВЫЕ пакеты, которые будут установлены:
  libgcc1
обновлено 0, установлено 1 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 2 пакетов.
Необходимо скачать 39,5 kБ архивов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 132 kB.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
Get:1 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian jessie/main amd64 libgcc1 amd64 1:4.9.2-10 [39,5 kB]
Получено 39,5 kБ за 0с (202 kБ/c)
E: Невозможно определить версию debconf. Он установлен?
debconf: ошибка при работе apt-extracttemplates: Нет такого файла или каталога
dpkg: ошибка: анализ файла «/var/lib/dpkg/status» около строки 73 пакета «multiarch-support»:
 присутствует несколько экземпляров пакетов, которые не могут быть установлены одновременно; вероятно это произошло из-за обновления с пом
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Для лечения предпринимались такие действия (хотя что-то мне подсказывает, что я сделал еще хуже...):

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/* -vf 
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
```

После этого команда `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, выдает это:

```
rostislav@Rostislav-PC:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: ошибка: анализ файла «/var/lib/dpkg/status» около строки 73 пакета «multiarch-support»:
 присутствует несколько экземпляров пакетов, которые не могут быть установлены одновременно; вероятно это произошло из-за обновления с пом
```

---

Как это можно исправить и из-за чего возникла проблема (первая)?

---

Содержимое файла `status`:

```
Package: multiarch-support
Status: install ok unpacked
Priority: required
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 193
Maintainer: GNU Libc Maintainers <debian-glibc@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: glibc
Version: 2.19-18+deb8u4
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-2)
Description: Transitional package to ensure multiarch compatibility
 This is a transitional package used to ensure multiarch support is present
 in ld.so before unpacking libraries to the multiarch directories.  It can
 be removed once nothing on the system depends on it.
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html

Package: libc6
Status: install ok unpacked
Priority: required
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 10231
Maintainer: GNU Libc Maintainers <debian-glibc@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: glibc
Version: 2.19-18+deb8u4
Replaces: libc6-amd64
Depends: libgcc1
Suggests: glibc-doc, debconf | debconf-2.0, locales
Breaks: hurd (<< 1:0.5.git20140203-1), libtirpc1 (<< 0.2.3), locales (<< 2.19), locales-all (<< 2.19), lsb-core (<= 3.2-27), nscd (<< 2.19)
Conflicts: prelink (<= 0.0.20090311-1), tzdata (<< 2007k-1), tzdata-etch
Conffiles:
 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf newconffile
Description: GNU C Library: Shared libraries
 Contains the standard libraries that are used by nearly all programs on
 the system. This package includes shared versions of the standard C library
 and the standard math library, as well as many others.
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html

Package: gcc-4.9-base
Status: install ok installed
Priority: required
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 218
Maintainer: Debian GCC Maintainers <debian-gcc@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: gcc-4.9
Version: 4.9.2-10
Breaks: dehydra (<= 0.9.hg20110609-2), gcc-4.4-base (<< 4.4.7), gcc-4.7-base (<< 4.7.3), gcj-4.4-base (<< 4.4.6-9~), gcj-4.6-base (<< 4.6.1-4~), gnat-4.4-base (<< 4.4.6-3~), gnat-4.6 (<< 4.6.1-5~)
Description: GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
 This package contains files common to all languages and libraries
 contained in the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC).
Homepage: http://gcc.gnu.org/

Package: multiarch-support
Status: install ok unpacked
Priority: required
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 193
Maintainer: GNU Libc Maintainers <debian-glibc@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: glibc
Version: 2.19-18+deb8u4
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-2)
Description: Transitional package to ensure multiarch compatibility
 This is a transitional package used to ensure multiarch support is present
 in ld.so before unpacking libraries to the multiarch directories.  It can
 be removed once nothing on the system depends on it.
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html
//ВОТ ТУТ 74 СТРОКА! <-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Package: libc6
Status: install ok unpacked
Priority: required
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 10231
Maintainer: GNU Libc Maintainers <debian-glibc@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: glibc
Version: 2.19-18+deb8u4
Replaces: libc6-amd64
Depends: libgcc1
Suggests: glibc-doc, debconf | debconf-2.0, locales
Breaks: hurd (<< 1:0.5.git20140203-1), libtirpc1 (<< 0.2.3), locales (<< 2.19), locales-all (<< 2.19), lsb-core (<= 3.2-27), nscd (<< 2.19)
Conflicts: prelink (<= 0.0.20090311-1), tzdata (<< 2007k-1), tzdata-etch
Conffiles:
 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf newconffile
Description: GNU C Library: Shared libraries
 Contains the standard libraries that are used by nearly all programs on
 the system. This package includes shared versions of the standard C library
 and the standard math library, as well as many others.
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html

Package: gcc-4.9-base
Status: install ok installed
Priority: required
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 218
Maintainer: Debian GCC Maintainers <debian-gcc@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: gcc-4.9
Version: 4.9.2-10
Breaks: dehydra (<= 0.9.hg20110609-2), gcc-4.4-base (<< 4.4.7), gcc-4.7-base (<< 4.7.3), gcj-4.4-base (<< 4.4.6-9~), gcj-4.6-base (<< 4.6.1-4~), gnat-4.4-base (<< 4.4.6-3~), gnat-4.6 (<< 4.6.1-5~)
Description: GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
 This package contains files common to all languages and libraries
 contained in the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC).
Homepage: http://gcc.gnu.org/
```

Comment: *E: Невозможно определить версию debconf. Он установлен?* — восстановить `/var/lib/dpkg/status` из `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old`, видимо, не удалось? ну, значит установите (на самом деле **пере**-установите) пакет *debconf*, о чём *dpkg* и напоминает.

Comment: *вероятно это произошло из-за обновления с пом* — строка обрезана. что там написано было в оригинале? // и, кстате, хотя бы для административных задач включайте вывод сообщений по-английски: очень трудно даже просто искать информацию в интернете на основании переводов оригинальных англо-язычных интерфейсов.

Comment: *анализ файла «/var/lib/dpkg/status» около строки 73* — что-то там в синтаксисе неверно. или два описания одного и того же пакета включено (если вы объединяли содержимое файлов `status` и `status-old`).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, 1.  Видимо нет, но я пытался :). 2. Хорошо, пойду искать, как переустанавливать пакет. 3. Строка не обрезана, в терминале она такая же. 4. А можно как-то отдельно включить перевод? Да хотя мне и пользовательский не сильно нужен, потом включу все и сразу. 5. Может и включено, я сейчас напишу сюда содержимое файла.

Comment: *как переустанавливать пакет* — с точки зрения dpkg в вашем случае это будет именно установка (ведь в файле `status` пакет не упоминается): `sudo apt-get install имя-пакета`. если apt-get не справится, попробуйте скачать файл с пакетом: `apt-get download имя-пакета` и установить этот файл с помощью dpkg: `sudo dpkg -i имя-файла.deb`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, пакет так и называется - `debconf`?

Comment: *А можно как-то отдельно включить перевод?* — в текущем сеансе оболочки: `export LC_ALL=C`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, `install` не работает, `download` тоже: `W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/home/rostislav/debconf_1.5.56_all.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Отказано в доступе)`. Нужно теперь вручную искать или так нельзя?)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40411/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-bukashka101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из длинной эпопеи в чате:

1. удалите одну из двух секций с описанием пакета `multiarch-support` в упомянутом файле `/var/lib/dpkg/status` (секции отделяются друг от друга пустой строкой).
2. затем скачайте и установите базовые пакеты:

   ```
   $ cd /tmp
   $ apt-get download debconf libgcc1 dpkg perl-base libbz2 multiarch-support libc6 
   $ sudo dpkg --install --force-all *.deb
   ```